# Rails Paperclip custom interpolation error on test

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, paperclip

When I try to use custom interpolation on tests they fail. however, everythings works fine on development environment and the test worked without custom interpolation + *sometimes* they work with the custom interpolation.

my code:

```
class ActiveSupport::TestCase
  fixtures :all
  def file_fixture(filename = "sample_file.png")
    File.new("test/fixtures/documents/#{filename}")
  end
end

test 'document attachment must be from valid file extension' do
    document = Document.new
    document.appeal_id = Appeal.first.id
    document.attachment = file_fixture('FailTest - bad filename extension.txt')
    assert_not document.valid?, 'Document attachment should not be TXT'
    document.attachment = file_fixture('Test - medical.pdf')
    assert document.valid?, 'Document attachment with pdf extension should be valid'
end
```

application.rb:

```
Paperclip.interpolates :year do |attachment, style|
  attachment.instance.created_at.year
end

Paperclip.interpolates :month do |attachment, style|
  attachment.instance.created_at.month
end

Paperclip.interpolates :appeal_id do |attachment, style|
  attachment.instance.appeal.id
end

Paperclip.interpolates :env do |attachment, style|
  Rails.env
end

Paperclip.options[:command_path] = 'C:\Program Files (x86)\GnuWin32\bin'
Paperclip::Attachment.default_options[:default_url] = '/images/missing.jpg'
Paperclip::Attachment.default_options[:path] = ':rails_root/public/attachments/:env/:year/:month/:appeal_id/:hash.:extension'
Paperclip::Attachment.default_options[:url] = '/attachments/:env/:year/:month/:appeal_id/:hash.:extension'
```

The error I get is:

```
Minitest::UnexpectedError: NoMethodError: undefined method `year' for nil:NilClass
    config/application.rb:27:in `block in <class:Application>'
    test/models/document_test.rb:43:in `block in <class:DocumentTest>'
```

And this is because in the `:year` interpolation the `created_at` resolves to `nil`

**My Question:**
Why does it resolves to nil only on the test environment and not all the time? (Another test successfuly added file to the path using the date interpulation)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the problem is that you have unsaved `Document` instance.
You just call `document = Document.new` so `document.created_at` is `nil`.

Try to get saved `Document` instance with `document = Document.create(...)` or by calling `document.save` before assertions.

Or you can manually assign `created_at` like
 `document = Document.new(created_at: Time.now)`

Or you can update interpolations code to work with `nil` values like

```
Paperclip.interpolates :year do |attachment, style|
  # it would be nil in case of created_at is nil
  attachment.instance.created_at.try(:year) 
end
```

Comment: your .try(:year) example worked. I think it is not being saved because of validation issues and therefore there is nothing in created_at. ...need to learn more about it, anyways - THANKS!

Comment: Yes, I think with `try` is the most suitable solution. By the way what does it interpolate it to with `:year` equal `nil`?